# How to gather support for tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonym-process

I proposed a tag synonym a few days ago. Out of curiosity I looked at the [tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) and found out that no one as voted.

I later found out that there are suggestions pending approval from  Mar 31<sup>st</sup>, 2012 which is more than *Three and a half years old*.

Hence my question is,

Is there a way to gather support for tag synonyms? (not essentially for our suggestions but on a whole)

Comment: Post here on meta, it's the only way you can get synonyms approved... seriously.

Comment: BTW, someone wanting to check which synonyms they can vote on can use http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest... maybe that link could be added to /review...

Comment: @Braiam Wouldn't that be like canvassing for our requests? I am asking in a general sense.

Comment: No, it would be backwards, because /synonyms would be visible and accessible to a bigger public. Through I said two statements I'm presuming the question is about the later suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The synonym I had proposed was for [repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/repeat/synonyms)

Comment: @Braiam preferably with puns.

Comment: While we're at it, anybody want to accept my `move`/`move-semantics` synonym request? Because the tag descriptions are almost identical...

Comment: Asked question [Questions with \[repeat\] are repeatedly tagged with \[repeating\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312506)

Comment: Why is it *still so difficult* to create, vote and get attention for synonyms? I remember asking a question (or was it an answer) about synonyms here many many years ago (my history appears to have been erased so I can't find it). It was difficult then, so it seems like nothing has changed.

Comment: @Mottie Unfortunately yes, the system hasn't changed. Your question was asked before the MSE/MSO split and has [remained on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138832/tag-synonyms-approval-process). As normal users, we all can't help much. If you have any tag suggestion, then please ask a meta post and link it to me. I'll try to make sure that it is synonymized (given that the community has agreed to it).

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok, I [posted it here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343788/tag-synonyms-for-virtual-keyboard). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to gather support for tag synonyms, but first, let us looks into the intricacies of who can approve a tag synonym. The tag synonym page makes this clear:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

So, in order to get a tag synonym you proposed approved, you need to find three other users who have a score of 5 in that particular tag. You can find users who are eligible for that by looking at the top users of that tag (`/tags/tagname/topusers`). However, please do not harass them by continuously pinging them using comments under their posts. Create a new chat room, and invite the users, with tag score 5, over. Discuss the reasoning as to why you feel that the particular tag synonym needs to be created. Let them make the final decision.

Apart from this, another way would be to ask a meta post. This is because the moderators can create tag synonyms, without the requirement of having the 5 score in that particular tag. When you create a new meta post, use the [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) tag, and post your question. Explain clearly and provide a convincing argument as to why you need to synonymize the tags. The meta users will then review your requests, vote on it and offer their suggestions. A moderator will then come over, check your post and the tags once again, and synonymize the tags.