# Merge [saml2] into [saml-2.0]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There's been three versions of SAML released: 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0.

The version mostly in use is SAML 2.0. There are two tags for that [saml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/saml2) (35 questions) and [saml-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/saml-2.0) (985 questions). I've suggested that [saml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/saml2) should be a synonym of [saml-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/saml-2.0).

I'd also like to have the two tags merged. AFAIK merging requires a moderator. Getting the synonym approved would also be good, as it is a relatively low traffic tag so I expect it won't be approved just by people noticing it.

Comment: Too bad the [tag synonyms page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) is so underused. I suppose very few people know about it, so there are only a handful of synonyms suggested and they rarely ever get enough votes to be approved or rejected. It's particularly ludicrous that a synonym suggested by ChrisF back in 2013 before he was a moderator still hasn't been added on.

Comment: @CodyGray Less than very few people care I guess. This question, [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312430) did not receive any attention at all! :-(

Comment: Is that true about requiring a moderator for a merge? I thought if you just re-tagged the questions, the defunct tag would be cleaned up.

Comment: @RichChurcher Retagging is a manual edit, that also bounces all posts to the top of the start page. AFAIK moderators have tools to do a batch migration of all relevant posts.