# Tag synonyms for [virtual-keyboard]

Tags: support, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

It seems like the only way to expedite getting tag-synonym approval is to ask a question...

I would like to create these synonyms ([already requested](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/virtual-keyboard/synonyms)) for [virtual-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-keyboard) (x276):

- [android-virtual-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-virtual-keyboard) (x51)
- [on-screen-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/on-screen-keyboard) (now merged with [osk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osk)) (x180)
- [uikeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikeyboard) (x872)

Comment: I'm not so sure about the [android-virtual-keyboard] but the [osk] and [on-screen-keyboard] are a perfect fit for synonyms.

Comment: Bad time to ask for synonyms: the top bar's got everyone's attention. :\

Comment: There is also the `uikeyboard` tag which could be a synonym of `keyboard`

Comment: I agree with Bhargav. [tag:osk] and [tag:on-screen-keyboard] are synonymous and were being used that way, so I merged them. [tag:on-screen-keyboard] is now the master tag. I'm not sure that [tag:uikeyboard] should be merged into or synonymized with anything, since it refers to a specific API. I don't know enough about [tag:android-virtual-keyboard] to make the call there, and don't feel comfortable doing anything unless this gets some more attention from informed community experts.