# Expedite Tag Synonym approval for [sql-update] and [sql-server-data-tools]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

After following these questions,

- [Why tag synonyms doesn't get attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347692/why-tag-synonyms-doesnt-get-attention)
- [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312430/how-to-gather-support-for-tag-synonyms)
- [Tag synonyms for [virtual-keyboard]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343788/tag-synonyms-for-virtual-keyboard)

It seems like asking a question is the only way to expedite getting tag-synonym approval...

I would like to create these synonyms:

* <s>[sql-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-update)  for [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) [(Check suggested synonym page here)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/synonyms)</s>
* <s>[sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) for [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) [(Check suggested synonym page here)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssdt/synonyms)</s>

Also, if there is another way to expedite tag-synonym approval, please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both tag synonyms was approved:

[ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) is considered as synonym of [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) ([Tag synonyms for sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-data-tools/synonyms))

[sql-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-update) is considered as a synonym of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) ([Tag synonyms for sql](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server-data-tools/synonyms))

Thank you all