# Why tag name is not changed on my profile after synonym approval

Tags: bug, tags, search, tag-synonym-process

From about two years i suggested to consider [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) as a tag synonym for [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools).

- [Expedite Tag Synonym approval for [sql-update] and [sql-server-data-tools]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347701/expedite-tag-synonym-approval-for-sql-update-and-sql-server-data-tools-and#347701)

I was checking the proposal status and i found that it is approved. But while checking my profile page, in the tag section the tag [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) is still showing in the Tags section.

[image]

And when i click on the tag it doesn't shows any result in the search form, while i have 62 answer. And the page mentioned that it is showing the:

> Results tagged with [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) Search option user 7031230

[image]

Even if i change the search keyword to `user:7031230 [sql-server-data-tools]`, it still not showing any results.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The profile page, top users page, etc are all heavily cached on the server side. It won't reflect changes immediately. It usually will change after a couple of hours, or after 1 complete day.

After that, if you happen to cross the required limits for receiving the tag based badges, you will be awarded that as well.

So, yeah, [you should blame caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: How can i know when the synonym was approved. If it is approved from a long time then i don't think this is right else you're 100% right

Comment: @Hadi, I am actually not sure of a way to see when a synonym has been approved.  (I approved the [ssdt] synonym today, which is how I know)

Comment: To be more precise, today we changed the the meta post related to the tag synonym suggestion. I think we should wait some hours and if this situation was changed i will mark this answer as accepted else i will give you a reply. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: @Hadi, sure. But just to be clear, your synonym suggestion had 3 approval votes, and needed one more to be approved. I approved it today, which is how the synonym was created. (A few minutes before you made the changes to the meta post)

Comment: Ahhh ok. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @BhargavRao Feature request for the devs to expand on mod tools? Or non-mod tools? :-D